# How to specify the backward command in pytorch to a specific agent?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

- [GitHub link to codebase](https://github.com/Schmeitzke/Hearts_ANN.git)
- [Link to game rules i follow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearts_(card_game)#Modern_rules_(2011))

I want to create an artificial neural network which plays the card game Hearts. I made the codebase in python 3.10 with the help of Pytorch. As an input layer i use a system which consists of a `[52][5]` size array which represent the 52 cards in the first dimension and in the second dimension i define the 5 characteristics of each card:

```
in playing agent’s hand `→` `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]`  
in any other player’s hand `→` `[0, 1, 0, 0, 0]`  
played in the current trick by the agent `→` `[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]`  
played in the current trick by other player `→` `[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]`  
consumed `→` `[0, 0, 0, 0, 1]`
```

This 2D list gets flattened into a input tensor of size 260. This gets followed by two hidden layers of size 128 and ends in an output layer of size 52, since a deck of cards has 52 cards. For the hidden layers i use ReLu and for the conversion to the output layer i use Softmax. All with a dropout rate of 0.2.

When i run the training file, which trains player 0 and 2 by playing against themself in a 1v1v1v1 match, i outputs some needed variables. The problem i am facing is that they do not show improvement after playing against each other. I believe this happens because in the training file the `backward()` command gets used but the system does not know which agent to backtrack. How  can I specify this or improve the code overall?

The link to the code is provided at the top of this message and i also included it below this message.

```
from typing import List

import numpy as np
import torch
from torch import float32

from ann_Hearts import Utility
from ann_Hearts.ANN_Hearts import ANN_Hearts


class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        self.current_player = -1
        self.starting_player = -1

        self.HEARTS_RANGE = range(0, 13)  # Based on Card.java
        self.CLUBS_RANGE = range(13, 26)
        self.DIAMONDS_RANGE = range(26, 39)
        self.SPADES_RANGE = range(39, 52)

    @staticmethod
    def deal_cards(playerList: List[ANN_Hearts]):
        # Reset hands of all players before new deal
        for player in playerList:
            player.card_vectors = np.zeros((52, 5), dtype=float)
        cards = np.random.permutation(52)
        sliced_shuffled_cards = np.array_split(cards, 4)

        for player_index, player_cards in enumerate(sliced_shuffled_cards):
            for card in player_cards:
                # The card is in this player's hand
                playerList[player_index].card_vectors[card][0] = 1.0
                # Mark the card as not in the other players' hands
                for other_player_index in range(4):
                    if other_player_index != player_index:
                        playerList[other_player_index].card_vectors[card][1] = 1.0

        # counter = 0
        # print("HANDS DEALT!")
        # for player in playerList:
        #     print("Hand player:", counter)
        #     for row in player.card_vectors:
        #         print(row)
        #     print()
        #     counter += 1

    def play_round(self, playerList: List[ANN_Hearts]):
        trick = [-1] * 4
        corrected_card = [False] * 4

        for i in range(4):

            # print("\nPLAY ROUND PLAYER:", self.current_player, "(current player)")
            # Prepare and forward pass tensor
            input_tensor = torch.flatten(torch.tensor(playerList[self.current_player].card_vectors, dtype=float32))
            # print("Input tensor:", input_tensor)
            output_layer = playerList[self.current_player].forward(input_tensor)
            # print("Output layer:", output_layer)

            # Interpret output layer
            outputLayer = output_layer.detach()
            # print("Output layer detached:", output_layer)

            # Retrieve cards in hand agent
            cards_in_hand = []
            for card in range(52):
                if playerList[self.current_player].card_vectors[card][0] == 1:
                    cards_in_hand.append(card)
            # print("Cards in hand:", cards_in_hand)

            # Determine best card which is in hand
            chosen_card_prob = -1
            chosen_card = -1
            for card_in_hand in cards_in_hand:
                if outputLayer[card_in_hand] > chosen_card_prob:
                    chosen_card_prob = outputLayer[card_in_hand]
                    chosen_card = card_in_hand
            trick[self.current_player] = chosen_card
            # print("Chosen card:", chosen_card)

            suit_starting_card = self.determine_suit_range(trick[self.starting_player])
            # print("Suit range starting card:", suit_starting_card)

            # If not starting player and the suit is in hand player, play best card in hand and in suit range
            if (self.starting_player != self.current_player and
                    Utility.is_suit_in_hand_player(suit_starting_card, playerList[self.current_player]) and
                    chosen_card not in suit_starting_card):

                cards_in_hand_correct_suit = []
                # print("Cards in hand and in suit:", cards_in_hand_correct_suit)
                chosen_card_prob = -1
                chosen_card = -1
                for card_in_hand in cards_in_hand:
                    if card_in_hand in suit_starting_card:
                        cards_in_hand_correct_suit.append(card_in_hand)
                for card_in_hand in cards_in_hand_correct_suit:
                    if outputLayer[card_in_hand] > chosen_card_prob:
                        chosen_card_prob = outputLayer[card_in_hand]
                        chosen_card = card_in_hand
                corrected_card[self.current_player] = True
                # print("Chosen card looking at hand and starting suit:", chosen_card)

            self.update_player_vectors_during_round(playerList, chosen_card)

            trick[self.current_player] = chosen_card

            # Advance turn
            self.current_player += 1
            if self.current_player == 4:
                self.current_player = 0

        # print("Trick:", trick)
        # print("Corrected card:", corrected_card)

        # counter = 0
        # print("\nHANDS UPDATED BEFORE RESETTING TRICK!")
        # for player in playerList:
        #     print("Hand player:", counter)
        #     for row in player.card_vectors:
        #         print(row)
        #     print()
        #     counter += 1

        self.update_player_vectors_after_trick(playerList)

        # counter = 0
        # print("\nHANDS UPDATED AFTER RESETTING TRICK!")
        # for player in playerList:
        #     print("Hand player:", counter)
        #     for row in player.card_vectors:
        #         print(row)
        #     print()
        #     counter += 1

        losses, round_winner = self.calculate_loss(trick, corrected_card)

        # print("Losses:", losses)
        # print("Round winner:", round_winner)

        return losses, round_winner

    def update_player_vectors_during_round(self, playerList: List[ANN_Hearts], card_index: int):
        playerList[self.current_player].card_vectors[card_index][0] = 0.0  # not in playing agent’s hand
        playerList[self.current_player].card_vectors[card_index][2] = 1.0  # played in the current trick by the agent
        playerList[self.current_player].card_vectors[card_index][4] = 1.0  # card consumed

        for other_player in range(4):
            if self.current_player != other_player:
                playerList[other_player].card_vectors[card_index][1] = 0.0  # not in any other player’s hand
                playerList[other_player].card_vectors[card_index][
                    3] = 1.0  # played in the current trick by other player
                playerList[other_player].card_vectors[card_index][4] = 1.0  # card consumed

    @staticmethod
    def update_player_vectors_after_trick(playerList: List[ANN_Hearts]):
        for player in range(4):
            for card in range(52):
                playerList[player].card_vectors[card][2] = 0.0
                playerList[player].card_vectors[card][3] = 0.0

    def calculate_loss(self, trick: [float], corrected_cards: [bool]):
        loss = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        totalLoss = 0.0
        for i in range(4):
            if trick[i] in self.HEARTS_RANGE:
                totalLoss += 2.0
            if corrected_cards[i]:
                loss[i] += 20
        round_winner = self.determine_round_winner(trick)
        loss[round_winner] += totalLoss

        return loss, round_winner

    def determine_round_winner(self, trick):
        round_winner = self.starting_player
        starting_card = trick[self.starting_player]
        suit_of_starting_card = self.determine_suit_range(starting_card)

        for player in range(4):
            if starting_card < trick[player] <= max(suit_of_starting_card):
                starting_card = trick[player]
                round_winner = player
        return round_winner

    def determine_suit_range(self, card: int):
        suit = -1
        if card in self.HEARTS_RANGE:
            suit = self.HEARTS_RANGE
        elif card in self.CLUBS_RANGE:
            suit = self.CLUBS_RANGE
        elif card in self.DIAMONDS_RANGE:
            suit = self.DIAMONDS_RANGE
        elif card in self.SPADES_RANGE:
            suit = self.SPADES_RANGE
        return suit
```

```
import random

import torch
import torch.optim as optim

from ann_Hearts.ANN_Hearts import ANN_Hearts
from ann_Hearts.Game import Game

# Number of epochs for training
num_epochs = 10000

# Initialize players (models)
player_1 = ANN_Hearts()
player_2 = ANN_Hearts()
player_3 = ANN_Hearts()
player_4 = ANN_Hearts()

player_1.train()
player_2.train()
player_3.train()
player_4.train()

playerList = [player_1, player_2, player_3, player_4]

# Optimizers for each player
optimizers = [
    optim.Adam(player_1.parameters()),
    optim.Adam(player_2.parameters()),
    optim.Adam(player_3.parameters()),
    optim.Adam(player_4.parameters())
]

played_wrong_cards = [0.0] * 4
total_losses = [0.0] * 4
total_games_won = [0.0] * 4

# Training loop
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    # Deal cards and set up game
    game = Game()
    game.deal_cards(playerList)
    game.starting_player = random.randint(0, 3)
    game.current_player = game.starting_player
    game.round = 1
    losses = []
    round_losses = [0.0] * 4

    # Play all rounds in a game
    for _ in range(13):
        losses, round_winner = game.play_round(playerList)
        # Update each player's model after a trick
        for i, player in enumerate(playerList):
            if i == 0 or i == 2:
                optimizer = optimizers[i]
                optimizer.zero_grad()

                # Convert loss to a tensor and ensure it requires gradient
                player_loss = torch.tensor([losses[i]], requires_grad=True)
                player_loss.backward()

                optimizer.step()

        game.starting_player = round_winner
        game.current_player = round_winner

        for i in range(4):
            total_losses[i] += losses[i]
            round_losses[i] += losses[i]

    game_winner = round_losses.index(min(round_losses))
    total_games_won[game_winner] += 1

    # Optional: Print epoch number and losses for tracking
    if epoch % 50 == 0:

        print(f"Epoch {epoch}, Losses: {total_losses}")
        # print("Amount of wrongly played cards:", played_wrong_cards)
        print("Total games won:", total_games_won, "\n")
        # played_wrong_cards = [0.0] * 4
        total_losses = [0.0] * 4
        total_games_won = [0.0] * 4

# torch.save(player_1.state_dict(), 'player_1_weights.pth')
# torch.save(player_2.state_dict(), 'player_2_weights.pth')
# torch.save(player_3.state_dict(), 'player_3_weights.pth')
# torch.save(player_4.state_dict(), 'player_4_weights.pth')
```

```
import numpy as np
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F


class ANN_Hearts(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, input_size=260, hidden_size=128, output_size=52):
        super(ANN_Hearts, self).__init__()

        # Define layers
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.output_layer = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.2)

        self.card_vectors = np.zeros((52, 5), dtype=float)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))  # ReLU activation for first hidden layer
        x = self.dropout(x)  # Apply dropout
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))  # ReLU activation for second hidden layer
        x = self.dropout(x)  # Apply dropout
        x = F.softmax(self.output_layer(x), dim=0)  # Softmax for output layer
        return x
```

```
from torch import Tensor

from ann_Hearts import ANN_Hearts


def is_card_in_hand_player(card: int, player: ANN_Hearts) -> bool:
    if player.card_vectors[card][0] == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def is_suit_in_hand_player(suit_range, player: ANN_Hearts) -> bool:
    suit_int_hand = False
    for card in suit_range:
        if player.card_vectors[card][0] == 1.0:
            return True
    return suit_int_hand


def get_cards_in_hand_within_suit(suit_range, player_object: ANN_Hearts) -> [float]:
    cards = []
    for card in suit_range:
        if player_object.card_vectors[card][0] == 1.0:
            cards.append(card)
    return cards


def get_best_card_in_hand_in_suit(suit_range, player: ANN_Hearts, output_layer: Tensor) -> float:
    allowed_cards_in_hand = get_cards_in_hand_within_suit(suit_range, player)
    highest_change = float('-inf')
    best_card = None
    for i in range(len(allowed_cards_in_hand)):
        if output_layer[allowed_cards_in_hand[i]] > highest_change:
            highest_change = output_layer[allowed_cards_in_hand[i]]
            best_card = allowed_cards_in_hand[i]
    return best_card
```